# Use of posting answers to the questions

Tags: discussion

Being a contributor on various forums, I know the importance of posting answers to the questions. According to me, it's important for both the OP and the one who answers. I see people with over 50K reputation here on this forum and felt asking this question.

- What do people gain by answering?
- How does answering help professionally?
- Is there any job profile where mentioning the reputation on workplace forum will help?

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to The Workplace SE.  As others have mentioned, we're not a traditional forum. Instead, we're a Questions and Answers site.  The major difference is the focus on answers, not discussion, and the result is a wealth of knowledge, without the noise generated by discussion, which can be searched from major search engines.

To learn more about how this site works, please [take the tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out what we consider [on-topic and off-topic on this site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The biggest benefit you'll get by contributing answers is that you'll learn. Answering questions will force you to think about the problem on a much deeper level and formulate an intelligent, quality answer which will last for years to come, helping future visitors to the site.  Hope this helps.

As far as I know, there is no site to highlight your contributions to Workplace SE, but I imagine one could experiment with putting this in their CV or resumé, if it's applicable to the job they're applying for.

Comment: I was one of the close voters on this question on the main site, but I am now having second thoughts. "Why do you answer questions here?" is definitely off-topic, but "does contributing to Workplace.SE help you in your professional career?" sounds like a useful question.

Comment: If I ever apply to be an astronaut, I will definitely mention my 138 rep on SE Space Exploration

Answer (score 0):

In addition to forcing you to think harder and formulate your ideas(as jmort mentioned), I enjoy helping people.

If I can provide a good answer to an question, I have potentially helped the asker and any future person who finds that answer later.

I would certainly consider including my workplace.se account on my resume when applying for management type jobs. Similar to how many developers include their stack overflow accounts. I think it would give a potential employer a lot of insight into my management style, writing ability, communication skills, judgement, etc.